# z-test for proportions where successes are less than 10

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, z-test

I have this data;

```
                          Success_amount                         Overall Attempts    p_val_vector actual_estimate     average_of_averages
1                                   0                                    398 0.999999999999999555911    0.0000000000         0.000841582
2                                   0                                   2205 0.319438680275828945643    0.0000000000         0.000841582
3                                   2                                   2504 0.999999999999999444888    0.0007987220         0.000841582
4                                   0                                    964 0.729535320742549231454    0.0000000000         0.000841582
5                                   0                                   1878 0.389887834976935909737    0.0000000000         0.000841582
6                                   0                                   2731 0.235335691267788527092    0.0000000000         0.000841582
7                                   0                                    757 0.863585487176445232294    0.0000000000         0.000841582
8                                   1                                   1524 0.999999999999998334665    0.0006561680         0.000841582
9                                   0                                    653 0.946683132537777138893    0.0000000000         0.000841582
10                                  0                                    413 0.999999999999999555911    0.0000000000         0.000841582
11                                  2                                   4430 0.524540057046991803347    0.0004514673         0.000841582
12                                  1                                   1054 0.999999999999998334665    0.0009487666         0.000841582
13                                  1                                   5649 0.135419686936719879666    0.0001770225         0.000841582
14                                  2                                   2773 0.999999999999997224442    0.0007212405         0.000841582
15                                  2                                   4655 0.473681382265657702213    0.0004296455         0.000841582
16                                  0                                   4010 0.117458553719864675080    0.0000000000         0.000841582
17                                  3                                   1522 0.281197454268709789993    0.0019710907         0.000841582
18                                  3                                   4466 0.893879853875587437884    0.0006717421         0.000841582
19                                  2                                   2546 0.999999999999998001599    0.0007855460         0.000841582
20                                  4                                   8442 0.328274863246539705397    0.0004738214         0.000841582
21                                  6                                   5412 0.657656158839843296704    0.0011086475         0.000841582
22                                 11                                   6286 0.023448224200527497535    0.0017499205         0.000841582
23                                  9                                   4837 0.028075226130280673403    0.0018606574         0.000841582
24                                  2                                   1260 0.669317879528037451564    0.0015873016         0.000841582
25                                  3                                   2968 0.998896576473299102616    0.0010107817         0.000841582
26                                 11                                   5307 0.004286833752223900666    0.0020727341         0.000841582
27                                  1                                    570 0.976609779523636478693    0.0017543860         0.000841582
28                                 20                                   4614 0.000000000000002217841    0.0043346337         0.000841582
```

And I'm conducting a z-test as follows:

```
for(i in 1:length(Success_amount)){
  prop <- prop.test(df$Success_amount[i], df$Overall_Attempts[i], p=average_of_averages, alternative = "two.sided")
  pval <- prop$p.value
  est <- prop$estimate
  p_val_vector[i] <- pval
  actual_estimate[i] <- est
}
```

Each row refers to a different person. I have two questions: Firstly, how do I treat values with high pvals, some of them almost 1? I assume it is due to the low amount of successes and not many attempts, but, for example it seems logical to me that #16 would have a low p value - he has a lot of attempts. It seems to me it is a result of me mis handling my data, but I'm unsure. Is there perhaps a different test I should be conducting to fit this data?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you modelling the same process? You cannot estimate the probability of success from the data and then estimate the p-value from that. The null hypothesis that the observations share the same success probability is rejected: `prop.test(dat$Overall, dat$Attempts)` gives `X-squared = 89.744, df = 27, p-value = 1.164e-08`.

Comment: @ping I don't understand exactly what you mean. the estimate is given to me by `prop`. I'm less interested in the estimate, I just added it to the data incase, I'm more interested in the comparison against the average of averages

Comment: If you run the `prop.test` you reject the hypothesis that the data have a common probability of success. Thus, using the average of averages estimate is not correct because you are assuming that the samples are drawn from a single binomial distribution. Edit: consider that `prop.test` requires successes to be > 0.

Comment: @ping That's my problem - how do i deal with success = 0? Is there even anything I can do? Logically I feel like theres nothing - I can't really reject the null hypothesis without having success

Comment: You can use Laplace smoothing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing.

Comment: @ping Thanks for pointing me there. Reading more about this technique on the internet, it basically means I should add 1 to each observation where 0 occurs? If so, I'm unsure how helpful it is - as I have in this data rows with success and still an almost-1 pvalue

Comment: You add one to each success and 1*num categories (2 for you) to the number of attempts. It’s based on the Bayesian posterior for a multinominal distribution using a Dirichlet prior https://towardsdatascience.com/estimating-probabilities-with-bayesian-modeling-in-python-7144be007815

Comment: @ping Thank you! That was an interesting read, and also, using the smoothing did improve the situation. Unfortunately, still have some high p-values - but I believe this is more of an issue with the data, not something statistics can fix.. If you have any more pointers, I would love to hear them :)

Comment: My only suggestion is to be careful about the prob estimation, if the average of the averages really represents the estimate of the global probability of success.